# Confused with image scaling and positioning in libgdx

Tags: java, graphics, libgdx, textures, game-engine

I'm having quite a bit of difficulty wrapping my head around the actual display side of things with libgdx. That is, it just seems fairly jumbled in terms of what needs to be done in order to actually put something up onto the screen. I guess my confusion can sort of be separated into two parts:

1. What exactly needs to be done in terms of creating an image? There's
   Texture, TextureRegion, TextureAtlas, Sprite, Batch, and probably a
   few other art related assets that I'm missing. How do these all
   relate and tie into each other? What's the "production chain" among
   these I guess would be a way of putting it.
2. In terms of putting
   whatever is created from the stuff above onto the monitor or
   display, how do the different coordinate and sizing measures relate
   and translate to and from each other? Say there's some image X that
   I want to put on the screen. IT's got it's own set of dimensions and
   coordinates, but then there's also a viewport size (is there a
   viewport position?) and a camera position (is there a camera size?).
   On top of all that, there's also the overall dispaly size that's
   from Gdx.graphics. A few examples of things I might want to do could
   be as follow:

   - X is my "global map" that is bigger than my screen
     size. I want to be able to scroll/pan across it. What are the
     coordinates/positions I should use when displaying it?
   - Y is bigger
     than my screen size. I want to scale it down and have it always be
     in the center of the screen/display. What scaling factor do I use
     here, and which coordinates/positions?
   - Z is smaller than my screen
     size. I want to stick it in the upper left corner of my screen and
     have it "stick" to the global map I mentioned earlier. Which
     positioning system do I use?

Sorry if that was a bunch of stuff... I guess the tl;dr of that second part is just which set of positions/coordinates, sizes, and scales am I supposed to do everything in terms of?

I know this might be a lot to ask at once, and I also know that most of this stuff can be found online, but after sifting through tutorial after tutorial, I can't seem to get a straight answer as to how these things all relate to each other. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

- Texture is essentially the raw image data.
- TextureRegion allows you to grab smaller areas from a larger texture. For example, it is common practice to pack all of the images for your game/app into a single large texture (the LibGDX “TexturePacker” is a separate program that does this) and then use regions of the larger texture for your individual graphics. This is done because switching textures is a heavy and slow operation and you want to minimize this process.
- When you pack your images into a single large image with the TexturePacker it creates a “.atlas” file which stores the names and locations of your individual images. TextureAtlas allows you to load the .atlas file and then extract your original images to use in your program.
- Sprite adds position and color capabilities to the texture. Notice that the Texture API has no methods for setting/getting position or color. Sprites will be your characters and other objects that you can actually move around and position on the screen.
- Batch/SpriteBatch is an efficient way of drawing multiple sprites to the screen. Instead of making drawing calls for each sprite one at a time the Batch does multiple drawing calls at once.

And hopefully I’m not adding to the confusion, but another I option I really like is using the “Actor” and “Stage” classes over the “Sprite” and “SpriteBatch” classes. Actor is similar to Sprite but adds additional functionality for moving/animating, via the act method. The Stage replaces the SpriteBatch as it uses its own internal SpriteBatch so you do not need to use the SpriteBatch explicitly.

There is also an entire set of UI components (table, button, textfield, slider, progress bar, etc) which are all based off of Actor and work with the Stage.

I can’t really help with question 2. I stick to UI-based apps, so I don’t know the best practices for working with large game worlds. But hopefully someone more knowledgeable in that area can help you with that.

Comment: So in general, Actor + Stage is more "powerful" than Sprite + SpriteBatch? Because Actors can have their own update methods and such?

So say I have a raw .png file that I would want to use in the game. What exactly would the pipeline be like? Atlas -> Region ->Texture -> Sprite/Actor?

Answer (score 2):

This was to long to reply as a comment so I’m responding as another answer...

I think both Sprite/SpriteBatch and Actor/Stage are equally powerful as you can still animate and move with Sprite/SpriteBatch, but Actor/Stage is easier to work with. The stage has two methods called “act” and “draw” which allows the stage to update and draw every actor it contains very easily. You override the act method for each of your actors to specify what kind of action you want it to do. Look up a few different tutorials for Stage/Actor with sample code and it should become clear how to use it.

Also, I was slightly incorrect before that “Actor” is equivalent to Sprite, because Sprite includes a texture, but Actor by itself does not have any kind of graphical component. There is an extension of Actor called “Image” that includes a Drawable, so the Image class is actually the equivalent to Sprite. Actor is the base class that provides the methods for acting (or “updating”), but it doesn’t have to be graphical. I've used Actors for other purposes such as triggering audio sounds at specific times.

Atlas creates the large Texture containing all of your png files and then allows you to get regions from it for individual png's. So the pipeline for getting a specific png graphic would be Atlas > Region > Sprite/Image. Both Image and Sprite classes have constructors that take a region.